# how do I get netplan working with a usb wireless dongle?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I am struggling to get [my wireless dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FGX8LBF) to do anything beyond showing up in ifconfig which I achieved by installing the rtl88x2bu driver.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VJqQQxGrKt/) is the result of running the wireless information script from elsewhere on these forums.

I hope those results make the issue obvious or there is a clear next step I should take that's been left out of other discussions I've come across. Thanks for anything you guys can think of!

I haven't tried too much besides trying to configure netplan based on how it's working in another machine on my network. That one was easier to setup since the wireless card is built in, I guess.

--small edit: the full interface is wlx00e04c341cea, I don't see it on the pastebin text. I can see the full name when I run the commands myself.

--edit 2: the file at /etc/network/interfaces just has a comment saying ifupdown was replaced with netplan, my netplan yaml file is in the pastebin link. Disregard the credentials, they are defaults I am replacing after I get this network running, thanks again!

--edit3: output for sudo netplan --debug generate:

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: Processing input file //etc/netplan/wireless.yaml ..
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: wlx00e04c341cea: adding wifi AP 'Ghome-ap'
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: wlx00e04c341cea: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: Generating output files..
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: wlx00e04c341cea: creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlx00e04c341cea.conf
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:911: creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netplan-wpa@wlx00e04c341cea.service
** (generate:1459): DEBUG: 00:04:43:912: NetworkManager: definition wlx00e04c341cea is not for us (backend 1)
```

hmm, looking at that, maybe the issue is I have not installed wpa_supplicant. I assumed everything networkd used was included by default for ubuntu server. I do remember installing wpa_supplicant on the other machine that's working, but I was starting it manually and didn't realize it was also used by netplan. I'm going to run with that assumption now and I'll report back if that works.

--final edit: yes! That worked, need to install wpasupplicant. In case anyone else runs into this issue and their netplan half-works and disables their ethernet connection, you can run dhclient to get your ethernet back.

Comment: Are you on a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: note: edit out your access point name and password from your wireless information script...

Comment: @heynnema I see your answer, I'm onubuntu server. I have run through the steps before in your answer for generate, apply, and reboot. Is there some additional thing I need to install or run in order to start network connectivity? I'll edit the other things you requested into my post. Thanks!

Comment: You weren't clear in your comment... did you set your .yaml file as I indicate, and then do the generate/apply/reboot? (you need to add back your access point and password). Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, I used my credentials and ran your commands in order. I still get "connect: Network is unreachable" from trying to ping a machine on the local network. I'll edit the debug output from netplan generate into my post, maybe it isn't succeeding.

Comment: But did you first edit wireless.yaml as I indicate?

Comment: Yes, you do need to install wpasupplicant.

Comment: ok, that's where I messed up. I installed it on my other machine, but I was using wpa_supplicant manually to connect to wifi and had no idea netplan was using it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/etc/netplan/wireless.yaml` file should contain:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlx00e04c341cea:
      addresses: [192.168.86.201/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.86.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.86.1,8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "xxxxx":
           password: "xxxxx"
```

then do a:

`sudo apt update`                # update the software databases

`sudo apt install wpasupplicant` # install wpa supplicant

`sudo netplan --debug generate`  # create config files

`sudo netplan apply`             # apply config

`reboot`                         # reboot computer

Comment: I have run through those steps and when I reboot and ping 8.8.8.8 or another server on the LAN I get "network is unreachable".

Comment: The wifi info script posted my info directly to pastebin which I was not expecting (my fault for not reading), I don't think I can take it down. I guess the whole internet can now see I used a default netgear password from 2008 for my secondary router :)

Comment: @user2118704 your network is working now, yes?

Comment: yes, I have marked your answer as accepted for helping me get to that point. I have also reached out to the people managing ubuntu's pastebin and got the url removed. If you wouldn't mind, you can also edit the router credentials out of your post as well, hah. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2118704 user creds removed